# Bootstrap Popover HTML Tags don't useful

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm testing this in JSFiddle and run well:

BODY

```
<!-- Popover Link -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a href="#" rel="popover" data-original-title="">Popover HTML tags</a>
</div>

<!-- Popover DIV content -->
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">Username</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(function(){
$('[rel=popover]').popover({ 
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
}
});
});
```

But in my webpage is unuseful...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S0LDI3R/qy9Az/386/)
[my testing page](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6cfaKJhvAVZeGlBc01NbjlMMTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What do you mean by unuseful?

Comment: In FSFiddle all is well, but in my webpage, with the same config don't work... do you understand me? sorry but I'm from Spain and my english is a little poor...

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess : You wonder why the popover not is automatically shown? You need to set the `trigger` option :

```
$(function(){
    $('[rel=popover]').popover({ 
        html : true, 
        trigger: 'hover',  //<---here
        content: function() {
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });
});
```

forked fiddle .> http://jsfiddle.net/q8CV4/

Comment: I apreciate your observation, but I need an "onclick" trigger. By default the trigger is on click.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to import the bootstrap script and css.

Insert the following at the end of your `<body></body>`.

```
<body>

    ...

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

[Bootstrap CDNS](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)